# Left adjoint to the inclusion of Boolean algebras into distributive lattices

Tags: category-theory, boolean-algebra, lattice-orders, universal-algebra

Let $\mathbf{Boole}$ be the category of Boolean algebras.

Let $\mathbf{BDL}$ be the category of bounded distributive lattices.

There is a fully faithful functor ${\mathbf{Boole} \rightarrow \mathbf{BDL}}$ and it has a left adjoint because Boolean algebras can be defined as  bounded distributive lattices with an additional unary operation satisfying some equations.

I have been unable to give or find an explicit description of the left adjoint.

Can anyone describe it or give a reference? (Please, no Kan extensions.)

Comment: It is unclear to me what you consider explicit. You can construct it by generators and relations – actually, your observation that boolean algebras are bounded distributive lattices with an extra operation satisfying extra equations suggests to me you already know this. So what do you find inexplicit about that?

Comment: It is difficult to answer. Compare, say, with the construction of the abelianization of a group. "By generators and relations" sounds more or less like "by the adjoint functor theorem" to me. Now, in connection to the question above:  if the answer by Pilcrow is correct then the unit of the adjunction is monic. Can you prove this with a construction by generators and relations?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by abelianisation either. The commutator subgroup does not consist of only the commutators – it is the subgroup generated them. Do you also find that inexplicit, or is that acceptable?

Comment: I find the construction using the commutator subgroup more explicit  than the suggestion that the relevant adjoint exists "by generators and relations". By the way, the construction using the commutator subgroup easily implies that the unit is surjective.

Comment: OK, so you are willing to accept closure operations as sufficiently explicit. Then the generators and relations approach should also be sufficiently explicit. Or is your complaint that no one actually says what generators and relations to use?

Comment: I don't have a complaint. If you think you have an explicit construction of the left adjoint then send it, please.

Comment: I have several constructions of the left adjoint. I am trying to find out which one best fits your requirements. I do not want to spend time writing a detailed construction and then have you complain that it is not explicit because we have not agreed what "explicit" means.

Comment: Well, I don't have any rigorous definition of "explicit" but, if among your several constructions, you have one that confirms or contradicts Pilcrow's solution, do send that one. In particular, it should become clear if the unit is monic or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every boolean algebra $B$ can be embedded in a powerset, namely the set of sets of boolean algebra homomorphisms $B \to \{ \bot, \top \}$.
(This is a weak version of Stone duality.)
We can use the same idea to construct the free boolean algebra on a lattice.
(For me, lattices are always bounded.)

For a lattice $A$, let $\textrm{pt} (A)$ be the set of lattice homomorphisms $A \to \{ \bot, \top \}$.
There is a natural lattice homomorphism $\eta_A : A \to \mathscr{P} (\textrm{pt} (A))$, defined by the following formula:
$$\eta_A (a) = \{ \mu \in \textrm{pt} (A) : \mu (a) = \top \}$$
Let $\mathscr{B} (A)$ be the boolean subalgebra of $\mathscr{P} (\textrm{pt} (A))$ generated by the image of $\eta_A : A \to \mathscr{P} (\textrm{pt} (A))$.
Disjunctive normal form tells us that every element of $\mathscr{B} (A)$ is a finitary join of a finitary meet of possibly negated elements of the image of $\eta_A$, but since $\eta_A$ is a lattice homomorphism we can do somewhat better: every element of $\mathscr{B} (A)$ is of the form
$$(\eta_A (a_0) \land \lnot \eta_A (a'_0)) \vee \cdots \vee (\eta_A (a_{n-1}) \land \lnot \eta_A (a'_{n-1}))$$
for some $a_0, a'_0, \ldots, a_{n-1}, a'_{n-1}$ in $A$.

Now consider $\eta_A$ as a lattice homomorphism $A \to \mathscr{B} (A)$.
I claim it is initial among all lattice homorphisms $\phi : A \to B$ where $B$ is a boolean algebra.
Suppose given such a $\phi$.
We have a map $\textrm{pt} (\phi) : \textrm{pt} (B) \to \textrm{pt} (A)$ induced by precomposition, and this induces a (complete) boolean algebra homomorphism $\mathscr{P} (\textrm{pt} (A)) \to \mathscr{P} (\textrm{pt} (B))$.
What does it do to $\eta_A (a)$?
Well, by naturality, it gets mapped to $\eta_B (b)$.
So the boolean subalgebra generated by the image of $\eta_A$ is mapped into the boolean subalgebra generated by the image of $\eta_B$, i.e. we get a boolean algebra homomorphism $\mathscr{B} (\phi) : \mathscr{B} (A) \to \mathscr{B} (B)$.
But $\eta_B : B \to \mathscr{B} (B)$ is an isomorphism, so we obtain $\phi = \eta_B^{-1} \circ \mathscr{B} (\phi) \circ \eta_A$.
This proves existence, and uniqueness is automatic because $\mathscr{B} (A)$ is generated (as a boolean algebra) by the image of $\eta_A$.

Note that I have not restricted to distributive lattices in the above discussion.
However, since every boolean algebra is distributive, if $\eta_A : A \to \mathscr{B} (A)$ were an injective map then $A$ would be distributive, so distributivity of $A$ is a necessary condition for injectivity of $\eta_A$.
In fact, it is also sufficient.

Suppose $A$ is distributive.
We must show that, for any $a_0$ and $a_1$ in $A$, if $a_1 \nleq a_0$, then there is some $\mu : A \to \{ \bot, \top \}$ such that $\mu (a_0) = \bot$ and $\mu (a_1) = \top$.
By Zorn's lemma, there is a maximal filter $F \subseteq A$ such that $a_0 \notin F$ and $a_1 \in F$.
Define $\mu (a) = \top$ if $a \in F$ and $\mu (a) = \bot$ if $a \notin F$.
This is a lattice homomorphism:

- Obviously $\mu (\bot) = \bot$ and $\mu (\top) = \top$.
- Since $F$ is closed under $\land$, if $\mu (a_2) = \mu (a_3) = \top$ then $\mu (a_2 \land a_3) = \top$ too.
  Since $F$ is upward-closed, if $\mu (a_2 \land a_3) = \top$ then $\mu (a_2) = \mu (a_3) = \top$, hence if $\mu (a_2) = \bot$ then $\mu (a_2 \land a_3) = \bot$.
  Thus $\mu$ preserves $\land$.
- Since $F$ is upward-closed, if $\mu (a_2) = \top$, then $\mu (a_2 \lor a_3) = \top$.
  Since $F$ is maximal among filters not containing $a_0$, $a_2 \notin F$ if and only if there is some $a_4 \in F$ such that $a_2 \land a_4 \le a_0$; so if $\mu (a_2) = \mu (a_3) = \bot$ then we have $a_4$ and $a_5$ such that $a_2 \land a_4 \le a_0$ and $a_3 \land a_5 \le a_0$, and since $A$ is distributive, we have $(a_2 \lor a_3) \land (a_4 \land a_5) \le a_0$, hence $\mu (a_2 \lor a_3) = \bot$.
  Thus $\mu$ preserves $\lor$.

This completes the proof.
Incidentally, the construction of $\mathscr{B} (A)$ I outlined is basically what the special adjoint functor theorem would construct, and the description of the elements of $\mathscr{B} (A)$ is what you would get from  a generators-and-relations construction.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very good question to ask yourself! The left adjoint called the **free Boolean extension** of a bounded distributive lattice – this should lead you to the right references. The simplest way to think about it is in terms of the Priestley dual: each bounded distributive lattice is the lattice of *clopen upsets* of a Priestley space (a certain ordered topological space), and its free Boolean extension is the Boolean algebra of *all clopen subsets* of this topological space.

If you are not comfortable with Priestley duality, you can restrict the above to the finite case: each finite distributive lattice is the lattice of upsets of a finite poset, and its free Boolean extension is the Boolean algebra of all subsets of this finite poset.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Pilcrow. I am not comfortable with Priestley duality but I  looked at the papers by Peremans and Grätzer-Schmidt. It is not clear to me why the free Boolean extension has the universal property of the unit of the adjunction I asked about. (It is not even clear to me if the Boolean extension is functorial.) How do you prove it?

Comment: @Boogie One thing you can do is think about the finite case. The category of finite BAs is dually equivalent to the category of finite sets, and the category of finite bounded distributive lattices is dually equivalent to the category of finite posets. The adjunction between finite BAs and finite bounded distributive lattices is then simply the adjunction between finite sets and finite posets.

Comment: @Boogie Alternatively, you can approach this syntactically and use the disjunctive normal form (DNF). Consider the set of all formal joins of formal meets of formal literals, a formal literal being an expression of the form $a$ or $\neg a$ for $a$ in your distributive lattice). Do we know how to compare two such formal joins? Do we know how to compute the negation of such a formal join? The answer is: yes! Then you can build your Boolean extension out of the equivalence classes of such expressions in DNF. The unit is then simply the inclusion map $a \mapsto a$. Does that make some sense?

Comment: @Boogie Here is an exercise that you might want to try: draw a four-element chain, say, $a < b < c < d$. Then try to extend it to a Boolean algebra by adding elements such as $\neg b$, $\neg c$, $\neg c \vee b$, etc. to your picture.

Comment: The papers I mentioned give fairly explicit descriptions of the free Boolean extension. So if this is really the unit I asked about then my question would be answered, but I still don't see it. Theorem 2.2 in the paper by Peremans gives a universal property: it says that ${D \rightarrow B(D)}$ is initial among {\em extensions}, but this is not the universal property of the unit I am looking for. Does the universal property of the unit follows from Peremans' result?

Comment: @Boogie It seems to me that some further work is needed to derive the full universal property. I am not sure how to do it Peremans' way, but to me the most natural approach (if one wants to take the syntactic way, as Peremans does) would be to start from the free Boolean algebra $F(D)$ over the underlying set of $D$, and then show that factoring it by the congruence "generated by $D$" yields the free Boolean extension $B(D)$. Here generated by $D$ means: generated by the set of pairs $\langle a, a \wedge b \rangle$ in $F(D)$ such that $a \leq b$ in $D$.

Comment: I would find it useful to understand why the assignment ${D \mapsto B(D)}$ is functorial. Is that easier?

Comment: @Boogie If you have a homomorphism $h\colon D_1 \to D_2$ you extend it to a homomorphism $B(D_1) \to B(D_2)$ which sends the join $\bigvee_{k} (a_{k} \wedge \neg b_{k})$ to $\bigvee_{k} (h(a_{k}) \wedge \neg h(b_{k}))$. You just check that this is (a) well-defined, (b) a homomorphism. That it preserves composition and identities should be clear.

Comment: Thanks for the comment on functoriality, @Pilcrow.  Is there a reference for it? I don't think it appears in the papers I have seen.

Comment: @Boogie I am not aware of one, although I imagine one exists somewhere.